# OpenStreetMap SDK for Android

Tags: android, sdk, openstreetmap

> **Hello** everybody, I search good OpenStreetMap SDK for android
>   development. Somebody can offer something...
>
> Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is the source of OpenStreetMap SDK for Adnroid (Java)

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk/

https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources

https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-tools

http://developer.skobbler.com/support#devSupport

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Cookbook](https://androidcookbook.com/) has some [OpenStreetMap articles](https://androidcookbook.com/ChapterView.seam?chapterId=1000).